# When multi-line text pasted into text input regex does not match the space

Tags: c#, .net, regex, text, typography

When user pastes something like this (from notepad for example):

```
multi
line@email.com
```

into input text box, the line break dissapears and it looks like this:

multi
line@email.com

But whatever the line break is converted to does not match this regex:
'\s|\t|\r|\n|\0','i'
so this invalid character passes through js validation to the .NET application code I am working on. 
It is interesting but this text editor does the same transformation, that is why I had to post original sample as code. I would like to find out what the line break got converted to, so I can add a literal to the regex but I don't know how. Many thanks!

Here is the whole snippet:

```
var invalidChars = new RegExp('(^[.])|[<]|[>]|[(]|[)]|[\]|[,]|[;]|[:]|([.])[.]|\s|\t|\r|\n|\0', 'i');

if (text.match(invalidChars)) {
       return false;
}
```

Comment: I think the correct regex will be `/^\.|[<>()\\,;:\s\x00]|(\.)./g`. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9k54pteh/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Your *immediate* problem is escaping.  You're using a string literal to create the regex, like this:

```
'(^[.])|[<]|[>]|[(]|[)]|[\]|[,]|[;]|[:]|([.])[.]|\s|\t|\r|\n|\0'
```

But before it ever reaches the RegExp constructor, the `[\]` becomes `[]`; `\s` becomes `s`; `\0` becomes `0`; and `\t`, `\r` and `\n` are converted to the characters they represent (tab, carriage return and linefeed, respectively).  That won't happen if you use a regex literal instead, but you still have to escape the backslash to match a literal backslash.

Your regex is also has way more brackets than it needs.  I think this is what you were trying for:

```
/^\.|\.\.|[<>()\\,;:\s]/
```

That matches a dot at the beginning, two consecutive dots, or one of several forbidden characters including any whitespace character (`\s` matches *any* whitespace character, not just a space).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - here it is

> vbCrLF

This is what pasted line breaks are converted to. I added (vbCrLF) group and those spaces are now detected. Thanks, Dan1M

http://forums.asp.net/t/1183613.aspx?Multiline+Textbox+Input+not+showing+line+breaks+in+Repeater+Control